# Visual Studio 2013: How to open basic C file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm learning very basic C programming, using visual studio 2013 as my ide. Whenever I create a basic project and save it, i can no longer run it later on (when I come back to finish coding) .

All I want to do is create basic .c or .cpp sources files. When i try to open them aftersaving them, i lose the option to build/compile them.

The only way i can get them to ever run is to create a new project everytime i start visual studio, and hit ctrl +d to add them into the new project.

Is there any way to run/build files by opening the .cpp file?

**Problem:**
From this 
[image: IMG]

To this??
[image: IMG]

Comment: Open the .vcxproj file, not the .c or .cpp file.

Comment: Visual Studio is based on Solutions (one or more project) and Projects (which contain source code). If you are going to use Visual Studio, you need to make sure you save your Project file at least. It includes the specific C or C++ files, compilation options, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use code blocks since you are still new to c++ http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads

Comment: If you are just trying to do simple examples I agree. Visual studio can be confusing to use at first. Though in the end it turns into a fantastic asset.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not, you must have a project. Save the project you created and keep using it.